# zebra css ignoring one element?

Tags: html, css

I've an HTML markup that I don't control:

```
<div id="container">
   <input type="hidden"/ >
   <div>...</div>
   <input type="hidden"/ >
   <div>...</div>
   <input type="hidden"/ >
   <div>...</div>
</div>
```

I want to apply zebra css to the divs only, of course `nth-child(odd)` will not work as all divs are odd.

What could be the right way to apply zebra looking using only css *no javascript* to this?

Comment: What's the question? Which divs do you want to select? A [mcve] would help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `nth-child`, that apply styles for all siblings elements, for this case is better to use `nth-of-type` which apply the match to only elements of the same type.

```
#container div:nth-of-type(odd){
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.one:nth-child(4n) {
  color: red;
}
.one:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia eaque impedit debitis repellat neque, voluptates labore sequi odit aut nesciunt ducimus magni accusamus, ab, eveniet hic unde quam voluptas quae.</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia eaque impedit debitis repellat neque, voluptates labore sequi odit aut nesciunt ducimus magni accusamus, ab, eveniet hic unde quam voluptas quae.</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia eaque impedit debitis repellat neque, voluptates labore sequi odit aut nesciunt ducimus magni accusamus, ab, eveniet hic unde quam voluptas quae.</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia eaque impedit debitis repellat neque, voluptates labore sequi odit aut nesciunt ducimus magni accusamus, ab, eveniet hic unde quam voluptas quae.</div>

</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/domucacodi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Would you mind explaining how do you arrive to the answer? whats the logic behind the `4n` and `4n + 2`

Comment: well your answer is definitely better , but 4n goes like 4 , 8 , 12 ... and 4n + 2 goes like 2 ,6 ,10 .. which is the desired zebra pattern

Answer (score 0):

By Zebra CSS, you mean alternative color pattern for divs right.

User **nth-child** property with **4n+2** value

```
div:nth-child(4n+2){
  background: #000;
}
```